# Installing a .exe package that runs .msi in Wix bootstrapper

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I'm trying to make a bootstrapper installer that installs my 'setup.exe', the problem is my 'setup.exe' runs 'MyApp.msi' with some add ons, I am trying to set it in the same PackageGroup under the same Id but still, the setup.exe can not read the 'MyApp.msi' package and give a reference error, any suggestions?

This is a simple Windows installer, also I can not change anything about the way that 'MyApp' is installing.

```xml
<Chain>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="MyAppInstaller"/>
</Chain>
```

```xml
<PackageGroup Id="MyAppInstaller">
        <MsiPackage Name ="MyApp.msi"
                    SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\Installers\MyApp.msi"
                    InstallCondition="!(loc.InstallCondition_$(var.Platform))"
                    Cache="yes"
                    Compressed="yes"
                    DisplayInternalUI ="no"/>
        <ExePackage Id="setup"
                    DisplayName="setup"
                    Cache="yes"
                    Compressed="yes"
                    PerMachine="yes"
                    Name="setup.exe"
                    SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\Installers\setup.exe"
                    InstallCondition="!(loc.InstallCondition_$(var.Platform))"
                    InstallCommand="/s"
                    UninstallCommand="/s"/>
    </PackageGroup>
```

I am expecting the installer to run only the 'setup.exe' referencing to the 'MyApp.msi' both compressed in the 'Bootstrapper.exe' if possible.

Comment: So the **`setup.exe`** you launch should launch the embedded **`setup.exe`** which in turn kicks off the **`MyApp.msi`**? Sorry, a bit confused what you are doing.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, I don't have an embedded **setup.exe**, I just have one **setup.exe** that will run **MyApp.msi** when launched but with some extra configuration, so I just need to launch the setup.exe. The problem is it doesn't take a reference to **MyApp.msi** when launched in the bootstrapper, as I specified in the thread.

Comment: You want the msi only as part of your setup.exe? Maybe a Payload node as child of ExePackage is what you are looking for. All you need is having the msi in the same directory as your setup.exe, correct?

Comment: @VolkerG, I've tried your idea about using the Payload node for the ExePakcage, regardless that I find it a logical solution, it gives me a **Windows Installer** popup giving me the **msiexec** command uses. When I click ok it skips the **MyApp** installation and continues with the next installer.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question I proposed is a wrong approach, it's just a way to show the **MsiPackage** and **ExePackage** under the same **PackageGroup**. I have found another solution to this problem, the extra configuration that is done by the **setup.exe** can be done within the bootstrapper itself, so I was able to run the **MyApp.msi** directly.